# g++ error linking functions from static library

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries

I have a Qt5 C++ program and I'm trying to link to a static library.  The static library is senselock/libsenseEIV.a (relative to the main.cpp file).  When I compile I see the output below:

```
                                                                      ^
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib -o test1 main.o   -Lsenselock/libsenseEIV.a -L/opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Core -lpthread 
main.o: In function `test1()':
/test1/main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `S4Enum'
/test1/main.cpp:58: undefined reference to `S4Enum'
/test1/main.cpp:71: undefined reference to `S4Open'
/test1/main.cpp:83: undefined reference to `S4Control'
/test1/main.cpp:102: undefined reference to `S4Close'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:216: test1] Error 1
11:55:27: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project test1 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.1 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

and in my .pro file I have

```
LIBS += -Lsenselock/libsenseEIV.a
```

in case that matters.  Can someone explain how to fix this error?  The undefined reference errors all relate to functions located in that libsenseEIV.a library.

I don't understand if the compiler can't find the .a file or there's some other error.

---

UPDATE: I tried this syntax

```
LIBS += -Lsenselock -lsenseEIV
```

but it generates error

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsenseEIV

Am I using the wrong library name?  If so how would I find the name?  (assuming this is compiled into the .a file)

Answer (score 3):

This part of your command line is wrong:

```
 -Lsenselock/libsenseEIV.a
```

Should be:

```
 senselock/libsenseEIV.a
```

(The `-Lfoo/bar.a` tells linker to *search* directory `foo/bar.a/` for libraries, which is *not at all* what you want.)

> No `-l` prefix?

You can specify linking with `libsenseEIV.a` in the following (mostly equivalent) ways:

```
senselock/libsenseEIV.a
-Lsenselock -lsenseEIV
-Lsenselock -l:libsenseEIV.a
```

Comment: No `-l` prefix?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the linker flags wrong, you should specify the library path after `-L` and the library name after `-l`. In other words you need to have both in the assignment to `LIBS` variable in your .pro file.

After all it turns out that you can use  `LIBS += -L$$PWD/senselock/ -lsenseEIV` for your case

Comment: Try the full path after `-L`, for example `-L/home/.../libs/senselock` and experimentally add `.a` to the lib name after `-l`

Comment: Strange but the full path worked.  If you want to update your answer to "LIBS += -L$$PWD/senselock/ -lsenseEIV" I'll check as accepted

Comment: Done. You can give it one more try and pass a path relative to your .pro file. But your solution with `$$PWD` variable is elegant enough.